# django admin search_fields with exclude

Tags: django, django-admin

With django search_fields in our django-admin site, we search the db for loads of stuff.
I want to have an exclude option in search_fields in the text box (or any other way)

example:
in my admin file :

```
 search_fields = ('name', 'os', 'owner__first_name', 'owner__last_name',)
```

and in the web page i'm looking for 'John' --> getting some results including john lennon

I would love to have 'John {"exclude": "Lennon"}'

--> this will give some results excluding john lennon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the search by defining a get_search_results method in your ModelAdmin subclass.
Haven't tested it though..

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'os')
    search_fields = ('name', 'os', 'owner__first_name', 'owner__last_name',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.exclude(owner__last_name__iexact='lennon')
        except:
            pass
        return queryset
```

Comment: yah, thanks, i'll override the set_search_results function